# What is the equivalent of this code for MacOS excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Can someone advise the equivalent code to use in **Excel for Mac** that would create the same result as the below does in Windows?

```
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "CAD DATA.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like the following function

```
Function GetDesktopPath() As String
    #If Mac Then
        GetDesktopPath = Mid(MacScript("tell application ""Finder""" & vbLf & "return desktop as alias" & vbLf & "end tell"), 7) 
    #Else
        GetDesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    #End If
End Function
```

in your code to make it work on both Mac and Windows

```
Path = GetDesktopPath & Application.PathSeparator
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "CAD DATA.xlsx"
```

Make sure `ActiveWorkbook` is actually what you want to use. You probably meant to use `ThisWorkbook`:

- `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has the focus (is on top) while this code runs. This can easily change by a simple mouse click or any other interference.
- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook this code runs at. This is much more reliable because it never changes by any user interaction.

---

① *Source of the MacScript: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54852-Returning-the-Desktop-Path*